# Spigot Server Crash on Shutdown

Tags: java, concurrency, minecraft

I am running my own plugin off Spigot for Minecraft. When I run my plugin on my local host, I have no issues. However, when I run the plugin on my remote server (Centos operating system) the server crashes each time.

When I shut down the server, the crash happens and I receive the following thread dump:
https://pastebin.com/mdQBJ56H

I run the following command:

```
    @Override
    public void stopGamemode(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!nPlayer.getBukkitPlayer().isOp())
            return;

        nPlayer.getBukkitPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "Stopping gamemode...");
        // Send players to the hub
        if (!Statics.isWindows()) {
            for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
                out.writeUTF("Connect");
                out.writeUTF("Lobby");
                player.sendPluginMessage(Statics.getJavaPlugin(), "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
            }
        }
        
        
        Statics.setShutdown(true);
    }
```

I then listen for the PlayerQuitEvent (to ensure all players are out of the world). When the online player count is less than or equal to 1, I shutdown the server:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void playerLogout(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
        NationPlayer nPlayer = Statics.getPlayerMap().get(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
        nPlayer.playerLogout(event);
        
        if(Statics.getShutdown() && Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 1) {
            
            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(Statics.getJavaPlugin(), new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    
                    Bukkit.shutdown();
                }
                
            });
            
        }
    }
```

Again, at the end of it all, I am met with the following crash report:https://pastebin.com/mdQBJ56H

In this crash report, I cannot find a single reference to my plugin (net.mcnations). I don't believe we are performing any mysql operations either, thus, I have no idea how this is happening or why this is happening.

Comment: Could you post to pastebin.com the MySQL error log from the remote Centos server? Please also consider posting Additional Information listed in next comment.  Thank You

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post from the remove Centos server, MySQL error log?  And other additional information requested?  The thread dump posted may have some clues I do not recognize.